# Cauchy-Riemann equation doubts

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, partial-derivative

First of all I want to tell I know this question is pretty awkward, but I've been working on it  and searching about it and I've not got anything which clears my doubts.

According to cauchy-riemann equation any $f(z)$ which returns just a real or imaginary part can't be derivable but it can be derivate via derivative definition.

e.g.: 
$$f(z)=i2xy\\
U_x=0; U_y=0; V_x=2y; V_y=2x$$
So, according to c-r isnt derivable, however via derivative definition we get it is; $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = i2x$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = i2y$.

What I'm misunderstanding?

Thank you.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: How did you get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$?

Comment: Sorry, now i fix it.

Comment: So this $f$ does not have a complex derivative and is not therefore holomorphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(z)$ should be a function of a complex variable $z=x+iy$.  In that case your function $f(z) = \Im {(z^2)}$ is the imaginary part of the $z^2$ function.  That makes perfect sense as a complex-valued function of a complex variable, but the derivative with respect to the complex variable $z$ doesn't exist.  The existence of partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to $x$ and $y$, just isn't strong enough to guarantee the existence of the derivative with respect to $z$ which is a much stronger condition and requires the Cauchy-Riemann Equations to be satisfied.

Comment: But imaginary set is inside complex set, so [0,y] is a complex number, isn't it? In addition (|z|^2)/dz is derivable in [0,0], isn't it?

Comment: $|z|^2=x^2+y^2$ is not differentiable.  Again it won't satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  $z^2=x^2-y^2+i2xy$ has a derivative everywhere.  If you think about the definition of derivative as a limit, saying $\lim{z\to a}$ means $z$ can approach $a$ from any direction in the complex plane.  Saying $x$ approaches $a$ or $y$ approaches $a$ is much weaker.

Comment: Your comment about the limit has been very helpfull, on the other hand I must to tell you |z|^2 is derivable at x=0 and y=0 and, of course, satisfies c-r ecuation, i.e.: Ux=2x;Uy=2y;Vx=0;Vy=0 at x=0 and y=0. So returning to the limit, when you said "any direction" it meant just both axes? Thank you very much again.

Comment: You're correct about $|z|^2$ having a derivative at $z=0$.  It's just not very interesting from the perspective of complex analysis where holomorphic functions are defined by the property of being differentiable on an open neighborhood.  By "any direction" for the $\lim_{z\to a}$, it does not mean just along the horizontal and vertical directions but any way that $a$ can be approached in the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x+iy) = 2ixy$ is differentiable as a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$, but is not complex differentiable.

One way to see this is to write $f$ in terms of $z$ and $\bar z$ rather than $x$ and $y$:
$$
    2ixy = 2i \left(\frac{z+\bar z}{2}\right)\left(\frac{z-\bar z}{2i}\right)
         = \frac{1}{2}\left(z^2 - \bar z^2\right)
$$
In these coordinates, the Cauchy-Riemann equations take the form $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} = 0$.  Here $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} = \bar z$, so $f$ is not complex differentiable.